# Django | changing pk view parameter breaks the view

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app I'm making where each user has a card, consisting of several text tiles.

Here's my models:

```
class Card(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="owner")


class Tile(models.Model):
    card = models.ForeignKey(
        Card, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="card")
    content = models.TextField()
```

I would like to populate the same HTML template with the card/tile data based on the URL, so I am passing the primary key of the card through the URL:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('card<int:pk>/', views.card, name='card'),
]
```

My question is about my views.  I am trying to pass only the tiles in that have a card foreign key with the primary key id that was passed through the URL.  So, this works:

```
def card(request, pk):
    try:
        card = Card.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if card:
            context = {
                'title': 'Card',
                'tiles': Tile.objects.filter(card=pk)
            }
            return render(request, 'cards/card.html', context)
    except:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()
```

However, this, does not work:

```
def card(request, card_pk):
    try:
        card = Card.objects.get(pk=card_pk)
        if card:
            context = {
                'title': 'Card',
                'tiles': Tile.objects.filter(card=card_pk)
            }
            return render(request, 'cards/card.html', context)
    except:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()
```

I get the following error: `card() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'`

Why is that?  I was under the impression I was just renaming the parameter for my view function...

Comment: I would suggest reading this again https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/. pk is passed as keyword argument (notice urlpatterns )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is generated from urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('card<int:card_pk>/', views.card, name='card'),
]

def card(request, card_pk):
    try:
        card = Card.objects.get(pk=card_pk)
        if card:
            context = {
                'title': 'Card',
                'tiles': Tile.objects.filter(card=card_pk)
            }
            return render(request, 'cards/card.html', context)
    except:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()
```

Comment: Oh perfect!  Thank you so much!!